# ActiveX works on localhost, doesn't work on external server

Tags: c#, activex, localhost

**Edit2:**
For users that are having the same problem, I have managed to solve it using [this page](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/C__Deployment.aspx?msg=3244347). Good luck!

**Edit:**
Apperently my problem is that I need to install the ActiveX component on the client computer. What is the right way to do this?

I wrote a small ActiveX component in C# which searches for removable drives like USB flash drives. I have followed the steps [here](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/csharp/WritingAnActiveXControlInCSharp.aspx), in short I wrote some code and did: `regasm AClass.dll /tlb /codebase`

I wrote the ActiveX component because it needs to get executed on an external server. So I made a small webpage which uses the ActiveX. When I use a localhost the code gets executed and my USB key gets detected. It even works from inside an ASP.NET page which is the final goal.

However, when accessing the page from an external server, the code doesn't get executed. I placed javascript alerts before and after loading the ActiveX component. The alert after loading the ActiveX doesn't even fire.

The webpage uses this code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript">
    alert("Loading ActiveX");
    var x = new ActiveXObject("ANamespace.AClass");
    alert(x.GetDrives());
    alert("Done");
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

I can post the C# ActiveX code although I think it isn't needed, it just tries to find removable diskdrives, and it did work fine on my localhost.

Note, this is actually my first time working with ActiveX. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you install the ActiveX control on the external machine?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by installing but I think I did. I ran the webpage on the external machine and the ActiveX control did work there.

Comment: Your ActiveX server needs to be installed on the machine that runs the javascript.  Keeping it on the server is not an option.

Comment: Allright thanks, can you explain to me how to install it on the machine that runs the javascript?

Comment: The simplest thing may be to just write an installer and have users download and run it first.  You can detect they need it by saying `new ActiveXObject()` inside of a `try` block.  If you catch an exception, you prompt them to download the installer.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I make an installer for the ActiveX object? A quick google shows me I need stuff like "classid" and .ocx or .cab. Is that correct? Any users that can show me an example?

Comment: You can do the install via the web using a .cab file.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751972(VS.85).aspx Good luck with that.  But an ActiveX control is just a DLL with a COM object in it and some registration in the registry.  You can write an installer that puts it in its correct place and does the registration.

Comment: And yes, this is a painful, poorly documented world you've entered.  Welcome.  If you have specific questions about the manifest format, you can try asking here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ieextensiondevelopment/threads to get more specialized eyes on the problem.

Comment: @jeffamaphone Haha I see. Thank you, I will do some research then!

Comment: Don't create new browser ActiveX code these days.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It isn't my first choise either. I have to do research whether or not this is a good option.

Comment: No need to do any research. It's a terrible option. It's a technology with no future (it had no future 10 years ago also!)

Comment: Not a lot of choice if you want to run native code in an IE extension.  You may be able to use Silverlight or Flash to solve your problem, or a server-side technology.  ActiveX, as David points out, should be a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure, that you installed ActiveX control on your target machine. I'm using RegDllView to check it. This utility is free and you can find it here: http://www.nirsoft.net/ (try use x86 and x64 it depends on you control ).
Good luck! :) As jeffamaphone says - "...this is a painful, poorly documented world you've entered.." it's true :)